# Can anyone tell me why this function is not adding node to last and how can i solve it?

Tags: c, nodes

here is the c language code:

```
struct node
{
  int num;
  struct node* next;
};

void add_last(struct node* head,struct node* new_node)
{
  new_node->next=head;
  head=new_node;
}
```

I dont need code , I only want to understand why this is not working
thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not working because you did not call it.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because C is call by value. You can't change the value of an argument (like `head`) inside a function, and expect the caller to notice.

This should really be a dupe, but I failed to find it.

There are two basic ways of fixing it:

- Returning the new value, or
- Passing a pointer to the value, so that the function can modify it.

The former is generally cleaner, if possible.

That would make it:

```
struct node * add_last(struct node *head, struct node *new_node)
{
  new_node->next = head;
  return new_node;
}
```

Comment: so how can i solve this case

Comment: and simply do `head = add_last(head, new_node)` where needed.

Answer (score 1):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) language parameters are **passed by value**, so changes made in function to this copy of pointer takes effect only in function body, after that changed copy of pointer is removed from scope and *lost*.

If you want to pass an '*reference*' ([c](/questions/tagged/c) doesnt support real references like [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) and modify this pointer, you have to pass an pointer to *pointer you want to modify*, like

```
struct node * add_last(struct node **head, struct node *new_node)
//                                 ^^
{
  new_node->next = head;
  head=new_node;
}

// Calling
add_last(&head, new_node);
```

Second opportunity is to return this pointer

```
struct node * add_last(struct node *head, struct node *new_node)
{
  new_node->next = head;
  return new_node;
}

// Calling
head = add_last(head,new_node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C is a "pass by value" language, the statement `head = ...;` only takes effect within the function body. If you want to alter the head pointer you need to derefference and assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer following question:

Given these program snippets:

```
int foo(int a)
{
  a = 1234;
}

...
int bar = 1;
foo(bar);
// what's the value of bar here
```

What is the value of `bar` right after the call to `foo`?

1 or 1234 ?